# how do I properly handle rest responses?

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

I want to handle error responses on Django restful framework to fit my needs, but I would like to know where exactly, and how I can handle properly those error responses like `400,200,403` in my case I want to return error 400 if query params are missing or None

```
class ServiceViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                      viewsets.GenericViewSet):

    queryset = Service.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ServiceSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        domain = self.request.query_params.get('domain', None)
        domain_id = Domain.objects.filter(name=domain).first()

        if domain is not None:
            self.queryset = self.queryset.filter(domain=domain_id)
        return self.queryset
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        from rest_framework.response import Response
        from rest_framework import status
        domain = self.request.query_params.get('domain', None)
        if domain is None:
            # here you can return you expected response 200, 300 etc.
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
        return super(ServiceViewSet, self).list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

> override the list method in your class.